# How to check if the sum of some records equals the difference between two other records in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sum, temp-tables

I have a view that contains bank account activity.

```
ACCOUNT   BALANCE_ROW   AMOUNT   SORT_ORDER
 111           1         0.00        1
 111           0         10.00       2
 111           0         -2.50       3
 111           1         7.50        4
 222           1         100.00      5
 222           0         25.00       6
 222           1         125.00      7
```

- ACCOUNT = account number
- BALANCE_ROW = either starting or ending
  balance would be 1, otherwise 0
- AMOUNT = the amount
- SORT_ORDER =
  simple order to return the records in the order of start balance,
  activity, and end balance

I need to figure out a way to see if the sum of the non balance_row rows equal the difference between the ending balance and the starting balance.  The result for each account (1 for yes, 0 for no) would be simply added to the resulting result set.

Example:
Account 111 had a starting balance of 0.00.  There were two account activity records of 10.00 and -2.5.  That resulted in the ending balance of 7.50.

I've been playing around with temp tables, but I was not sure if there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this.

Thanks for any input you may have!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), then group rows by `ACCOUNT` calculating totals along the way:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY SORT_ORDER)
  FROM data
),
grouped AS (
  SELECT
    ACCOUNT,
    BALANCE_DIFF = SUM(CASE BALANCE_ROW WHEN 1 THEN AMOUNT END
                     * CASE rnk WHEN 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END),
    ACTIVITY_SUM = SUM(CASE BALANCE_ROW WHEN 0 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)
  FROM data
  GROUP BY
    ACCOUNT
)
SELECT *
FROM grouped
WHERE BALANCE_DIFF <> ACTIVITY_SUM
```

Ranking is only used here to make it easier to calculate the starting/ending balance difference. If starting and ending balance rows had, for instance, different `BALANCE_ROW` codes (like `1` for the starting balance, `2` for the ending one), it would be possible to avoid ranking.

Comment: Nice approach, allows you to select only those rows where the sum and row value are different.  +1 for elegance :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, but should be really close for comparing the summed balance with the balance_row as you've defined in your question.

```
SELECT  
    Account,  /* Account Number */
    (select sum(B.amount) from yourview B 
        where B.balance_row = 0 and
        B.account = A.account and
        B.sort_order BETWEEN A.sort_order and 
           (select max(sort_order) /* previous sort order value on account */ 
            from yourview C where  
            C.balance_row = 1 and  
            C.account = A.account and 
            C.sort_order < A.sort_order)
    ) AS Test_Balance,  /* Test_Balance = sum of amounts since last balance row */
    Balance_Row   /* Value of balance row */
FROM yourview A 
WHERE A.Balance_Row = 1
```